# ffmpeg need perfect pixels for LED processing (h264, mpeg 1, 2)

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg-2, lossless

[image]
We have .mov with Animation codec and the pixels look great.  But the LED media players are looking for h264, mpeg-1 or mpeg2.  Is this even possible to get high pixel accuracy?  I read a lot of the comments and tried the h264 lossless to no avail.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the media player supports 4:4:4 input, then you can output without smearing pixels.

Comment: Interesting.  It is 4:2:0.        But I have found players that do support 4:4:4.  Your saying if I get one of those players it will work because of 4:4:4 even with h.264 compression?

Comment: The H264 decoder of those players should support 4:4:4 input.